# How to setup Javamail to use client certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, smtp, certificate, jakarta-mail

There is a postfix smtp server (not controlled by me) that requires clients to send/use their client certificate in order to identify the sender.

How do I select the certificate that is sent? Or how can I select a keystore/truststore?

This is for a spring application running on tomcat using javamail.

update #1:
I can connect using AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory similar to the one from apache commons, so I can supply my own key-/truststore. But the connection now just hangs after sending the SSL handshake.

Using the MailSSLSocketFactory I get:

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 40
[Raw write]: length = 45
0000: 16 03 01 00 28 87 43 6A   F0 96 6A 8D E3 2F 2F 19  ....(.Cj..j..//.
0010: 7D 0A 8B 9A 24 AD DD 29   64 BF 0B 0F A2 EE 1F F7  ....$..)d.......
0020: 1A 3C 7B D8 06 82 73 66   B9 E5 02 12 3B           .<....sf....;
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 2F                                              ./
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, illegal_parameter
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
```

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  You might also need to enable the JDK's SSL debug output.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to it right now (until Monday) but it says main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 132 (or something like that)
and then it just stops. I'll see if I can get more debug output but that's all I have now.

Comment: Do you get different output if you don't use your special socket factory?  Do you just get an SSL handshake failure?  Note that you can also use [MailSSLSocketFactory](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/MailSSLSocketFactory.html) to specify your own KeyManager and TrustManager.

Comment: Without my socket factory the connection fails with a SSL error as the server's certificate is not trusted (pkix path building failed or something). I will definitely try the mentioned factory, I was unaware of that - thank you!

I also had a few problems with setting the properties correctly, right now, when I specify mail.x.x.port = A and mail.x.x.x.y.port = B it connects to port B. But but if I only specify mail.x.x.port it connects to port 465. Sorry I don't have the actual x and y values at hand - they're most likely socketFactory and ssl or something like that.

Comment: If you set the ssl.enable property, it will look for the ssl.socketFactory first, and use the ssl.socketFactory.port.  If you don't set those, or don't set ssl.enable, it will look for the plain socketFactory properties.

Comment: I tried the MailSSLSocketFactory now (updated my Question).
Also, regarding the port numbers: The lib does indeed try to connect to the specified port, but it logs the default port:

SMTPSSLTransport(SMTPTransport).openServer(String, int) line: 2013
 
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.acme.net", port 465, isSSL true

At this point it did not yet check the properties.

Comment: Looks like you're down to an SSL problem, not a JavaMail problem.  The JDK supports a bunch of SSL cipher suites, some of which are disabled by default.  You might want to check the list to make sure the one your server wants to use is not disabled in the JDK you're using.  I have no idea what the "illegal_parameter" error means.

Comment: Yup - thank you for your help! (I thought maybe the somewhat misleading logging could be of interest to you)